# Python: Parse file names, split, and strip multiple characters

Tags: python, csv, string-parsing

I have a folder containing images (.jpg), and I need to extract the file names to CSV, split them using `'_'` into multiple columns (with headers), and strip out multiple characters.

I have partially completed this using the following:

```
import os, csv

with open('filepath.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk('dirpath'):
        for item in files:
        writer.writerow([item])

with open('filepath.csv', 'w') as inf:
    with open ('outfile.csv', 'w') as outf:
        for line in inf:
            outf.write(','.join(line.split('_')))
```

Example file name:
`firstname_lastname_uniqueid_date_latUKN_longUKN_club.jpg`
The result of my code above returns `firstname`, `lastname`, `uniqueid`, `date`, `latUKN`,`longUKN`, and `club.jpg`.

This is the schema I'm looking for but I'd also like to parse out the `'lat'` and `'long'` from `latUKN`, and `longUKN`, as well as remove the `.jpg` at the end of the string. I need to remove the strings `'lat'` and `'long'` because there are file names containing latitude/longitude, but the `'lat'` and `'long'`are brought along in the parsing (e.g. `lat12.34, long54.67`)

How can I remove/strip out these other characters, and add headers? If there is no latitude or longitude, how can I leave this part empty instead of populating the string `'latUKN'`,`'longUKN'`. Is it possible to run this over a whole directory and output a single csv?

**Sample Data**

```
John_Doe_2259153_20171102_latUKN_longUKN_club1.jpg
John_Doe_2259153_20171031_lat123.00_long456.00_club1.jpg
Jane_Doe_5964264_20171101_latUKN_longUKN_club2.jpg
Jane_Doe_5964264_20171029_lat789.00_long012.00_club2.jpg
Joe_Smith_1234564_20171001_lat345.00_long678.00_club3.jpg
```

How data looks with current code:

```
John|Doe|2259153|20171102|latUKN|longUKN|club1.jpg
John|Doe|2259153|20171031|lat123.00|long456.00|club1.jpg
Jane|Doe|5964264|20171101|latUKN|longUKN|club2.jpg
Jane|Doe|5964264|20171029|lat789.00|long012.00|club2.jpg
Joe|Smith|1234564|20171001|lat345.00|long678.00|club3.jpg
```

How I want the data to look:

```
John|Doe|2259153|20171102|UKN|UKN|club1
John|Doe|2259153|20171031|123.00|456.00|club1
Jane|Doe|5964264|20171101|UKN|UKN|club2
Jane|Doe|5964264|20171029|789.00|l012.00|club2
Joe|Smith|1234564|20171001|345.00|678.00|club3
```

Comment: if this is the filename firstname_lastname_uniqueid_date_uknLatitude_uknLongitude_club.jpg the output you require is firstname_lastname_uniqueid_date_Latitude_Longitude_club

Comment: Yes, that is the required output, but just split on `_` to organize into columns (with headers). I've gotten the stings to split on `_` so each portion of the string is listed in its own column of the csv, but I need to also strip out the `'ukn'` and the `.jpg'` and add headers to row 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both answers revolved around using find/replace, and did not fully resolve the problem, I used the following to I complete the task:

```
import csv

infile = open('path', 'r')
outfile = open('path', 'r')

findlist = ['lat', 'long', '.jpg.']
replacelist = ["", "", ""]

rep = dict(zip(findlist, replacelist))

s = infile.read()
for item, replacement in zip(findlist, replacelist):
    s = s.replace(item, replacement)
outfile.write(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this if a is the given string?

```
    a="ukn_abcd.jpg"
    for i in "ukn",".jpg":
         a=a.replace(i,"")
```

You can make a function like this and pass the string to it to remove these unwanted characters

Comment: This could work, but how would I iterate it to run through the whole csv?

Answer (score 0):

```
  import csv
  l=[]
  with open("sf.csv") as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
       l.append(row)
  #print(l)
  new_l=str(l).replace("lat","").replace(".jpg","").replace("long","")
  #print(new_l)
  with open("output_sf", "w") as csvfile:
      for data in str(new_l).split(","):
          #print(str(data))
          csvfile.write(str(data))
```

So when I read your input file as you had given in your example above this is the output I get. Now you can try writing this to your txt/csv file.

> [['John|Doe|2259153|20171102|UKN|UKN|club1' 
>   'John|Doe|2259153|20171031|123.00|456.00|club1' 
>   'Jane|Doe|5964264|20171101|UKN|UKN|club2' 
>   'Jane|Doe|5964264|20171029|789.00|012.00|club2' 
>   'Joe|Smith|1234564|20171001|345.00|678.00|club3']]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158088/discussion-between-chetan-vasudevan-and-andrew-r).